# Can't debug Rust code inside vscode with WSL setup

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can't debug my rust code which is in WSL with VScode which is installed on my windows. I get these errors during `debug`.

```
Error: there is no registered task type 'codelldb.cargo'. Did you miss installing an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?
Error: there is no registered task type 'codelldb.cargo'. Did you miss installing an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?
```

Here is my `launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug executable 'foo'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--bin=foo",
                    "--package=foo"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "foo",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
    ]
}
```

Strangely I can `run` my code using vscode & getting expected output.

I have installed below extension for WSL in vscode

```
codeLLDB
rust-analyzer
```

these are the versions of software

```
WSL: version 1
vscode: 1.72.2
windows : Windows 10
```

What I'm missing here

Comment: Does it work if you click the "Debug" button next to your `fn main()`? (requires `rust-analyzer` plugin installed)

Comment: No it doesn't work there as well

Comment: Can't help you sadly, I'm on WSL2 and it works for me. Maybe look at the rust-analyzer bug tracker if someone has similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to WSL version. Issue got fixed after upgrading WSL from v1 to v2